# How to smoothly approximate a sign function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, trigonometry

I have a function that defined as following

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x > 0$ } \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$ } \\
-1, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}$$
In practice, the $f(x)$ is approximated by a smooth $\tanh(kx)$ or [Heaviside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) function as bellow figure. Could you have other way to represent the $f(x)$ function? What are the benefits of your way?

**Update**: $\tanh(kx)$ function 
$k$ controls the smoothness of the sign function. As $k \to \infty$, the function defined in $f(x)=\tanh(kx)$ converges to standard sign function. Similarly, the derivative of $\tanh(x)$ also converges to Dirac delta function as $k \to \infty$. If $k$ is too small, the evolution equation for $x$ acts locally only on a few values around $\{x=0\}$. Hence, the $\tanh(kx)$ function is sensitive with parameter $k$. The parameter $k$ must be chosen carefully.

*Hence, My purposed want to reduce/ignore the affect of k, but remains the above smoothly approximation.*

[image]

Comment: Of course, one can improve the approximation by taking $\tanh \lambda x$ for some $\lambda \gg 0$.

Comment: what sort of benefits are you looking for?

Comment: It is more smooth and more simple

Comment: More smooth and more simple is $f(x)=0$. You must need something about the error too.

Comment: @Travis: Actually, I am looking for a other function not the $\tanh$ function

Comment: It would help if you explain why you want something other than the $\tanh$ function.  What is it about $\tanh$ that doesn't work for your purposes?  Otherwise, people may waste a lot of time coming up with other functions that also won't work for you.

Comment: Check out the function $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2} x>0; =0 $ for $ x<0$. It is infinitely differentiable at 0 and you can use it to glue together stuff.

Comment: Another suggestion; for $x\geq 0$ we have $f(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$ and for $x<0$, $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}-1$. With some $\lambda \gg 0$.

Comment: Yes. I update my question. Let see my analyze and my goal

Comment: $\mathcal C^{\infty}$ gluing together of jump discontinuities can always be accomplished by [these functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function). For more details see Spivak M., *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geomtery*, Vol. I p. 33. Particularly, you can make the interval where it "makes the jump" as small as you want.

Comment: You could use $\sqrt[3]{\tanh(kx)}$ which makes the $0$ point vertical (though the *curve* is smooth, even if the function isn't at $0$)

Comment: You will not find any such function. The idea is that this approximation means that you first take some reasonably good approximation $f$ and then you consider the sequence of functions $x \mapsto f(\lambda x)$ for $\lambda >0$. These approximations will naturally depend on $\lambda$ (the larger it is, the better the approximation). Yuo will have to live with this.

Comment: Can you _quantify_ the sense of "approximation" you want, in some metric(s) on spaces of functions, or seminorms, or ...?

Comment: Please explain "Hence, My purposed want to reduce/ignore the affect of k, but remains the above smoothly approximation." This is pretty obscure.

Answer (score 6):

You could try $\frac 2 \pi \arctan \lambda x$ for various $\lambda >0$. If you do not tell us what exactly you are looking for, we shall not be able to help.

Comment: Yes. I update my question. Let see my analyze and my goal

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is usually called "sigmoid" functions in the machine learning community, of which some can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Another way to do it is to perform local integration on the sign function:

$$a_1(x_0) = \frac{1}{2\delta_x}\int_{x_0-\delta_x}^{x_0+\delta_x} s(x)dx$$

And you could do this over and over, recursively:

$$a_n(x_0) = \frac{1}{2\delta_x}\int_{x_0-\delta_x}^{x_0+\delta_x} a_{n-1}(x)dx$$

You would gain one degree of differentiability every time you do so.

[image]

Comment: Any sigmoid function has the problem that the OP mentioned in his edit.

Comment: So just multiply with 2 and then subtract 1.

Comment: Why remove the comment afterwards? Destroys the communication.

Comment: Multiplying by 2 and subtracting one gives you $\tanh(\frac{x}{2})$ and OP seems to be against use of tanh. Apologies.

Comment: Not for all sigmoid functions. There is a long list at the end of the wikipedia page.