# Poisson Kernel in the upper half-plane is an identity approximation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I read that the Poisson Kernel for the upper half-plane, $K_y(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$ is an approximation to the identity. The text states this without proof and I am hoping to see a proof of this fact. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Numerator should be $y$ not $y^2$. Take a look at [Dirac's $\delta$ distribution smooth approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216448/568204). Use what I explained there with $n=1$, $\zeta(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $c=1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo you are right! My mistake. Also, I am having trouble following your other answer. I think it’s just a bit over my head. I corrected the error above.